# Winit example window not opening on WSL2

Tags: rust, windows-subsystem-for-linux, x11, wayland, winit

My ultimate goal is to use Pixels in WSL to create a data visualization in Rust.

However, I couldn't get the Pixels examples to run and so I first want to make sure Winit can run properly.
Downloading the Winit repository from GitHub and running the `window` example works correctly.

[image: 'window' example running in the Winit source repository]

However, if I create a new project and copy-paste the example code to it then running the code does not open a window anymore.

[image: [![Same example code running in my own project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slLOh.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slLOh.png)]

From running gdb, the code appears to get stuck in `window.request_redraw()` but I couldn't find much else out.

I am not super knowledgeable in windowing systems, but from running `echo $DISPLAY` and `echo $WAYLAND_DISPLAY` I get `:0` and `wayland-0`, respectively, which I believe indicates that WSL has both X11 and Wayland functionality installed.

I am using `Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS`. Running `cat /proc/version` prints `Linux version 5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 (oe-user@oe-host) (x86_64-msft-linux-gcc (GCC) 9.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.34.0.20200220) #1 SMP Fri Jan 27 02:56:13 UTC 2023`.

I seem to have some misunderstanding of how Cargo manages dependencies, since I don't know why the same code would run inside the Winit source project but not in my own project when I instruct Cargo to download the same version of the Winit source. I have tried Winit v0.29, v0.28, and v0.27 and the same problem persists.

Steps to reproduce:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/rust-windowing/winit.git
cd winit
cargo run --example window
```

window opens fine...

```bash
cd ..
cargo new window
cd window
cargo add winit
cargo add simple_logger
cp ../winit/examples/window.rs src/main.rs
mkdir src/util
cp ../winit/examples/util/fill.rs src/util
cargo run
```

window does not open...

Comment: Try copying the `[dependencies]` and `[dev-dependencies]` from their Cargo.toml into your `[dependencies]`.

Comment: Please provide the error *text* as [formatted text, not as image!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: @cafce25 my apologies!

Answer (score 2):

Solved!

TL;DR the example code had a feature flag that I didn't enable in my own project.

---

After fruitlessly debugging the main example code in `window.rs` I tackled the helper code in `fill.rs`. There is one function `fill_window()` with two signatures:

```
#[cfg(all(feature = "rwh_05", not(any(target_os = "android", target_os = "ios"))))]
pub(super) fn fill_window(window: &Window) {
    ...
}
    
#[cfg(not(all(feature = "rwh_05", not(any(target_os = "android", target_os = "ios")))))]
pub(super) fn fill_window(_window: &Window) {
    // No-op on mobile platforms.
}
```

The first one should run when the `rwh_05` feature is enabled and `target_os` is not  `android` or `ios`.
Otherwise, the second one should run.

I put a `println!()` in each and discovered that my `window` project was compiling to the second (no-op) function while the source `winit` project was compiling to the first function.

So either `target_os == android`, `target_os == ios`, or `rwh_05` is not enabled.

I ran some tests by adding code to `fill.rs`

```
#[cfg(target_os = "android")]
compile_error!("target_os = android");

#[cfg(target_os = "ios")]
compile_error!("target_os = android");

#[cfg(target_os = "linux")]
compile_error!("target_os = linux");
```

The output shows that `target_os` is `linux`.

```
error: target_os = linux
  --> src/util/fill.rs:16:1
   |
16 | compile_error!("target_os = linux");
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: could not compile `window` (bin "window") due to previous error
```

Next,

```
#[cfg(feature = "rwh_05")]
compile_error!("rwh_05 feature enabled");

#[cfg(not(feature = "rwh_05"))]
compile_error!("rwh_05 feature is not enabled");
```

The output shows that `rwh_05` is not enabled⠀

```
error: rwh_05 feature is not enabled
  --> src/util/fill.rs:16:1
   |
16 | compile_error!("rwh_05 feature is not enabled");
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: could not compile `window` (bin "window") due to previous error
```

And this is where I had my revelation.

I had mistakenly put the following in `Cargo.toml` thinking that it would enable `rwh_05` *globally*, when in reality it only enabled that feature for the `winit` crate and not my own local project.

```
[dependencies]
winit = { path = "./winit", features = ["rwh_05"] }
```

Adding

```
[features]
rwh_05 = []
```

to `Cargo.toml` and running with `cargo run --features rwh_05` runs the window example as expected:

[image]